# Fredhopper not returning correct data on first page load

Tags: smarttarget

We are running across a scenraio where fallback content is displayed on first page load instead of promotional content, while after a page refresh, we see the promotional data to be displayed on the webpage. Could anyone provide some pointers on what we could check from our end.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: I would suspect this is a timeout? Maybe because the full stack is still initializing and therefore it takes longer than the default of 200 milliseconds to get a response from Fredhopper. The logs should tell you if this is the case.

Comment: I second Nuno's comment about timeouts. It is the most common case, especially on developer machines where people do not hesitate to bounce the application pool or the whole web server :)

Comment: As per Nuno's comment if the issue is occurring because of timeout your log should be as below: You can configure timeout as per following doc http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-472D803D-95B1-4626-9792-9AEE9D2FB639      ERROR TimeoutQueryRunner - The fredhopper query timed out
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_17]'code'